# How do I know if a process has timedout in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, timeout

How do I know if "executable" has actually timed out?
timeout 1 ./executable

I need a condition to check in an if-statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From `man timeout` (*GNU coreutils 8.25*):

> If  the  command times out, and --preserve-status is not set, then exit
> with status 124.  Otherwise, exit with the status of  COMMAND.

So, you can check the exit code contained in $?, if it's 124, the command timed out:

```
timeout 1 ./executable

if [ $? -eq 124 ]; then 
    echo "the command timed out"
fi
```